# How do I get all sessions data in Symfony?

Tags: php, session, symfony1, symfony-1.4

How do I get all session data in Symfony?

Is it `$this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()`?

Answer (score 7):

Give a try to:

```
$this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->getAll();
```

Refs: [sfUser.class.php](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony1/symfony1/blob/master/lib/user/sfUser.class.php#L268) & [sfNamespacedParameterHolder.class.php](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony1/symfony1/blob/master/lib/util/sfNamespacedParameterHolder.class.php)

Answer (score 2):

The default namespace for all the session variables is 'symfony/user/sfUser/attributes'. You can get hold of all the session data like this:

```
$this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->getAll('symfony/user/sfUser/attributes');
```